# How can I draw 2D triangles in Unity 5?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, draw

I'm trying to draw 2D triangles using [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LoadOrtho.html) or [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LoadPixelMatrix.html) (scripts) but unsuccessfully (I don't see any triangles). I have only camera, canvas and panel in it, also I've tried to apply it on empty canvas's child object, how must I apply these scripts? I've tried different variations. And is it a good way to draw triangles or is there something better? Also I've read somewhere that GL Class doesn't work on iOS and/or Mac, is it true?

Comment: What is the z of the triangle, compared to other objects? if the z is less, the triangles will be hidden from view.

Comment: I've tried "0" on empty object on empty scene. I think I just use it somehow wrong.

Comment: Try putting the Z at 1, see if that helps.

Comment: I've tried. Also I've tried to change Z on existed objects, it doesn't affect at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private GameObject m_goTriangle;
m_goTriangle.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        m_goTriangle.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        m_meshTriangle = m_goTriangle.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        m_meshTriangle.Clear();
        m_meshTriangle.uv = new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0.25f), new Vector2(0.25f, 0.25f) };
        m_meshTriangle.vertices = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0.25f, 0), new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0) };
        m_meshTriangle.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
```

Hope this helps!  =)

Answer (score 3):

Just to remind that in Unity 5.6 (or higher/lower version?), the uv is NOT allowed to have different size of vertices'.
So... if you having trouble using Junamai's code, i.e. Unity get an error like:
`Mesh.uv is out of bounds. The supplied array needs to be the same size as the Mesh.vertices array.`

Just change the order of modifying uv and vertices:

```
    private GameObject m_goTriangle;
    m_goTriangle.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    m_goTriangle.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    m_meshTriangle = m_goTriangle.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    m_meshTriangle.Clear();
    m_meshTriangle.vertices = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0.25f, 0), new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0) };
    m_meshTriangle.uv = new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0.25f), new Vector2(0.25f, 0.25f) };
    m_meshTriangle.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
```

And the error will be solved.

Comment: I also had to add material: `m_goTriangle.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default")) {color = Color.red};`